# Agregar divs alrededor de otro div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tengo lo siguiente:

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.x-y-center {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.g {
  font-size: 55px !important;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  margin: 25px 0px 25px 0px;
}

.d {
  font-size: 25px !important;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  margin: 25px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.g:hover,
.d:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css?v=1">
<div class="container ">

  <div class="g x-y-center btn btn-primary">
    <b>G</b>
  </div>

  <div class="d x-y-center btn btn-success">
    <b>D</b>
  </div>

  <div class="d x-y-center btn btn-success">
    <b>D</b>
  </div>

  <div class="d x-y-center btn btn-success">
    <b>D</b>
  </div>

</div>
```

Quisiera poder lograr esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve intentando con `jquery`, pero caigo en una infinidad de condicionales (`if-else if-else`) validando coordenadas y posiciones.

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer de una forma sencilla y dinámica?

Comment: `.container > :nth-of-type(1) `  para seleccionar el hijo número 1  , aplicando un `transform: rotate(0deg) translate(10em) rotate(0deg);` aumentando de 45 grados por cada hijo. y así para todos los hijos que desees.

Comment: @DevJoel podrías añadir un ejemplo? creo que tu solución es lo que busco, gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primero asignamos una posición `absoluta` para todos los elementos `.container > {position: absolute;` para luego poder manipular y aplicarles una transformación básica de `rotación` y  `traslación`. además de aplicarle algunas propiedades adicionales como el `border-radius` para darle estilo de circulo entre otras .
Recordar que los grados aplicables a la rotación pueden variar dependiendo de los elementos que tengas, `(360/cantidadelementos) = TotalGradosaplicables` en mi ejemplo son 6 elementos sería = 60 grados aplicables ,

```css
.container > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  padding-top: 20px !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
}

.padre{
width:120px;
height: 120px;
left: 48%;
top: 180px;
padding:40px !important;
font-size:30px !important;
}
.container > :nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(10em) rotate(0deg);
}
.container > :nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: rotate(60deg) translate(10em) rotate(-60deg);
}
.container > :nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(120deg) translate(10em) rotate(-120deg);
}
.container > :nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(10em) rotate(-180deg);
}
.container > :nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(240deg) translate(10em) rotate(-240deg);
}
.container > :nth-of-type(6) {
  transform: rotate(300deg) translate(10em) rotate(-300deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css?v=1">
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn btn-success">
    <b>D</b>
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-success">
    <b>D</b>
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-success">
    <b>D</b>
  </div>
  <div class="d btn btn-success">
    <b>D</b>
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-success">
    <b>D</b>
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-success">
    <b>D</b>
  </div>
 
  <div class="padre btn btn-primary">
    <b>G</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DevJoel Muchas gracias, esto era lo que estaba buscando, una última cosa, con que propiedad puedo separar un poco más los elementos hijos del padre?

Comment: con la traslación , `translate(20em)`

Answer (score 3):

Realmente esto lo puedes realizar con CSS y, aunque te librarás de los condicionales (if-elses), no te librarás de hacerlo con posiciones (al menos con esta solución).

Lo que te propongo es que el círculo principal lo posiciones con `position: relative` y englobes el resto de círculos verdes dentro del mismo posicionandolos con `position: absolute`.

De esta manera, como un elemento posicionado con `position: absolute` se puede posicionar tomando referencia el elemento padre posicionado, podremos posicionar los círculos verdes con respecto al círculo azul. Para ello necesitarás hacer uso de las propiedades `top`, `left`, `bottom` y `right`.

**¿Cuál es la ventaja de hacerlo de esta manera?**

Que en cualquier lugar en el que posiciones el círculo azul los círculos verdes estarán posicionados respecto a este y no tendrás que recalcular las coordenadas en las que se encuentra de nuevo el círculo azul.

Ejemplo con tres círculos alrededor del círculo azul:

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.x-y-center {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.g {
  font-size: 55px !important;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  margin: 25px 0px 25px 0px;
}

.d {
  font-size: 25px !important;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  margin: 25px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.g:hover,
.d:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}


/* Nuevas clases */

.container{
  max-width: 120px;
}

.principal{
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

.absoluto{
  position: absolute;
}

.primero{
  top: -75px;
  left: 20px;
}

.segundo{
  top: -50px;
  left: -35px;
}

.tercero{
  top: 5px;
  left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css?v=1">
<div class="container ">

  <div class="principal g x-y-center btn btn-primary">
    <b>G</b>
    <div class="primero absoluto d x-y-center btn btn-success">
      <b>D</b>
    </div>
    <div class="segundo absoluto d x-y-center btn btn-success">
      <b>D</b>
    </div>
    <div class="tercero absoluto d x-y-center btn btn-success">
      <b>D</b>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```